# Trying to Print Multiple Trading Cards at Once via Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-quality, digital-printing

The reason I'm trying to print directly from Photoshop is to keep the image quality. Converting to JPG was my first idea, copy pasting the cards to a word doc or something to get a full page but that didn't work because converting a PSD to a JPG is a quality disaster. The trouble I'm having with Photoshop is that even though the size of the document I'm trying to print (*a white background with eight cards on it, all sized exactly as I want them*) is 8.5x11 inches, as is the paper I'm trying to print onto, the printable area in Photoshop is tiny! I can barely fit one card into it! It's ridiculous! My coworkers have shown interest in the cards and have given me tips and notes so I really want to finish this project but I'm not made of money, I work minimum wage, I can't keep testing things willy nilly, wasting ink and paper! I'm currently using Adobe Photoshop 2022. Help!

Comment: PSD to JPG shouldn't be 'a disaster' unless you've got your scaling wrong somewhere. Try to PNG instead, which is lossless. If it's still 'a disaster' then the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks! Hope you're having a good one, stranger!

Answer (score 1):

There are two places I can think of that could be causing the issue. The first would be to verify in the Image Size that you are working with 8.5 x 11 and 300 DPI canvas.

[image: Image Size Dialog Box]

Another place to check would be in the Print Dialog box itself:

[image: Print Dialog Box]

To find this section you might have to scroll the window a bit. Here you can verify that the dimensions are what you expect and if its still not looking correctly you can check "Scale to Fit Media" and that should visually fit your card sheet onto the 8.5 x 11 piece of paper.

There could be several other factors at play, but I would start here. Good luck!